# Qt : How to send keyevent to system?

Tags: c++, qt

I am doing a `Qt` project, and I want to send `keyevent` to system in programming.

I have tried the code below, but it doesn't work,

```
QKeyEvent event = QKeyEvent(QEvent::KeyPress, Qt::Key_B, Qt::NoModifier);

QApplication::sendEvent(this, &event);
```

To make my question more clearer, what I am doing is : I generate `char` in my app, and then want to send `keyevent` to `User.exe`, so that the `IME` can catch the `input char`. ( A custom  `input method` )

Answer (score 0):

I think QApplication::sendEvent can not implement what you desired. If you have a keyboard connected to your computer, there is a file in the directory of "/dev/input" named event0 or event1 or event3... and one file corresponds to your keyboard. You can try to open the file with linux API and construct input_event, then write the event to the file. Then your application will accept a key event just like you press a key on your keyboard.